# Scalar vs list context

Tags: perl

Wonder what is the rationale behind following two examples giving different results when in both cases `do {}` returns lists.

```
perl -wE 'say my $r = do {  (44); }'
44

perl -wE 'say my $r = do {  my ($x) = map $_, 44; }'
1
```

Comment: You have an explicit scalar context (`my ($x) = ...`) in your second example.

Comment: Not quite, you can check `$x` is 44, and `$r` is 1. `$x` would also be 1 if it was scalar context.

Comment: Well `perl -MO=Concise ...` shows differences but I can't explain where the context list/scalar is really set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both cases the assignment to $r is forcing scalar context on the do. However in the first case scalar context on a list returns the last value of the list, '44'.

In the second instance the assignment to `my ($x)` forces a list context, The result of assigning to a list in scalar context is the number of elements on the right hand side of the assignment. So you get.

`map $_, 44` returns a list of length 1 containing (44)

`my ($x) =` assigns the results above in list context, because of the brackets around `$x`, to the list `($x)` making $x = 44

The `do` block is in scalar context because of the assignment to `$r`, note the lack of brackets, and as I said above this returns the length of the right hand side of the list assignment. 1 in this case.

See what happens if you do this:

```
perl -wE 'say my $r = () = (1,3,5,7)'
```

Comment: Not all scalar contexts are equal. :-) `my $r = () = (1,3,5,7)` vs `my $r = (1,3,5,7)`

Comment: () = (1,3,5,7) is a list assignment to an empty list. $r = ... is a scalar assignment from ( () = (1.3.5.7) ) which gives the number of elements assigned to the empty list.

Comment: @Сухой27, Re "*Not all scalar contexts are equal*". Not quite. Not all **assignment operators** are equal. There is a **scalar assignment operator** (which returns its LHS as an lvalue in scalar context), and there's a **list assignment operator** (which returns the number of scalars returned by its RHS in scalar context). See the link in my answer for more details.

Comment: Re "*returns a list of length 1*", That's just a weird way of saying "returns a single scalar".

Answer (score 5):

First of all, neither `do` returns a list. They are evaluated in scalar context so they must return a single scalar, not an arbitrary number of scalars ("a list").

In the first case, the `do` returns the result of evaluating `44` in scalar context. This returns `44`.

```
scalar(    44    ) ⇒ 44
```

In the second case, the `do` returns the result of evaluating a list assignment in scalar context. This returns the number of elements returned by the right-hand side of the assignment.

```
scalar(    () = 44    ) ⇒ 1
```

I believe the real cause of your confusion is that you don't know about the assignment operators and how they are affected by context. If so, see [Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129) for the answer to your real question.